# What can you do at a stash?

Tags: running-with-rifles

These are scattered throughout the levels, and are even visible on the map as an icon of a box under a canopy, and the label 'stash'. There doesn't seem to be any way to interact with them though.

What can you do with stashes?  And how do you interact with them?  None of the bindings under controls seem to be related to this.

[image: Stash]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the RWR handbook:

http://runningwithrifles.gamepedia.com/Manual

> **Stash** is basically a container where you can store weapons, items and all other stuff which can be picked up. Stuff you have stored to stash is saved and can be accessed through every stash within a map and also available between rounds in singpleplayer campaign or online invasion.
>   A stash is primarily used to store rare weapons if those can only be used at a later time because of the higher XP requirement. It is also wise to put grenades and vests into the stash if you happen to be at a location without an armory around and would want such type of equipment.
>   The content of the stash is server specific and not carried over between servers. 
>   To interact with a stash keep F pressed while on front of it and drag and drop items from either your equipment or your backpack to the stash container.

Comment: I wonder why someone voted me down, I just try to help and you will find your answer in the link along with much more useful stuff.

Comment: I'm assuming because link only answers are bad, you should edit the relevant parts from your link into your post. Because once that link goes down, noone is helped anymore. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Ah ok, well that link won't go down as it's the official wiki for the game but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Josh Thanks for moving the relevant info from the manual here, and particularly for adding the bit on the end about how to interact with the stash.  Didn't realize you could hold F to bring up the inventory, that's new since I played last.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Oh wow if you didn't know that with the hold F, then you indeed missed quite a bit! :)
I added it at the ended to be sure as it might have been unclear for some people, good thing that I did indeed!